# iOS 7 autoresizingmask is not working correct

Tags: ios7, autoresizingmask

I am using in my code something like this

```
Btn.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin + UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

It works fine for all iOS versions except iOS 7.

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin is also working but UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin is not.

If somebody solved it please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

have you set the superview's `autoresizesSubviews` to `YES` ? and add `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` and check whether the resizing happens.